# AudioQueue buffer size for streaming aac audio

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am playing MP3 audio form a network stream and sometimes gaps are present when using WIFI connection.

I decrease the buffer size, but I am wondering what is the best method for calculating buffer size.

My MP3 stream is 64 Kbits.

I am using 3 buffers, for 64 *1024 each.
PacketDescriptions is 512

Thanks a lot

Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

Best values for me are :

Number of buffers       3
Buffer size         32 * 768
Max packets description     4096

Comment: How did you find this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why did you choose only 24576 bytes.
Wasn't it so small for buffer?